# Open Launch URL in an my app web view

Tags: java, android, android-studio, push-notification, onesignal

Hello i set up onesignal Notification in my android app web view

but android when open notification will launch web browsers not in android app.

i want launch web url into  my app

please help me

Comment: Paste the code used for WebView here.?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

Comment: <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

Comment: http://www.wzayefalarab.com/mainjava.txt

Comment: http://www.wzayefalarab.com/mainxml.txt

Comment: FragmentWebInteractive : need code of this class. show me the code of this class

Comment: http://www.wzayefalarab.com/fragmentwe.txt

Answer (score 0):

Put below code inside your FragmentWebInteractive class :

```
private class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
    Context context;

    public MyWebChromeClient(Context context) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
    }
}
```

remove previous code for setting webViewClient and then set the web chrome client to webview as following :

```
   webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient(this));
```

Comment: The fact is I do not know how to implement this

Comment: Add this code at the end of Fragment (before class end tag)

Comment: let me do it for you. Will paste the class here

Comment: I created the code and it opens in the browser, not the application

Answer (score 0):

Ankit Mehta Is partially correct. Not only will you need a webChromeClient but you will have to declare the specific scheme, host & path pattern in your manifest along with the proper category for the specific activity you wish to open only specific urls with. If you wish to open any link you can omit the host & path.

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:host="yoursite.com" />
                <data android:host="www.yoursite.com" />
                <data android:pathPattern="/subdirectory" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: How do I do this?

Comment: copy the snippet and place it just after the <activity> in the androidManifest.

Comment: I created the code and it opens in the browser, not the application

Comment: remove the last 3 lines because they will only ask your app to open using the app if it matches those urls remove:   <data android:host="yoursite.com" />
                <data android:host="www.yoursite.com" />
                <data android:pathPattern="/subdirectory" />

Comment: <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
                <data android:scheme="http" />
</intent-filter>

Comment: Tell me choose a browser

Comment: Alright I think we are getting close. you placed the code in the wrong place. you need to move it to your main activity not the splash activity